# Python: Not understanding why lambda is required in GUI "command=" to call function

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

in the process of learning Python.
I understand the use of lambda, here's an example and link(for others).

[Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

```
mult3 = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Would assign [3, 6, 9] to  mult3.

---

Here is the code I was required to do in the book's quiz:

```
import tkinter

def counter(text):
    """Add 1 every time the button is pressed"""

    count = int(text.get())
    text.set(count + 1)


window = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

var = tkinter.IntVar()
var.set(0)

button = tkinter.Button(window, textvariable=var, command=lambda: counter(var))
button.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

That is the verified solution. What I had come up with was the same except for the code in variable button.
Here's my line:

```
button = tkinter.Button(window, textvariable=var, command=counter(var))
```

The absence of lambda prevents the counter from working. I don't understand why lambda is required? As I'm just calling a function I had made, I'm not requiring a new unnamed function..?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: In your version of the code `counter(var)` is only executed once. In their version it is executed every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Do you know why though? I'm trying to understand

Comment: Think about it more generally.  When you pass a function arguments like `f(3 + 7)`, you're not passing `3 + 7` into the function, you're passing `10`.

Comment: @Yabusa: what do you mean "why?" There is no deeper reason than that it is how the language works. In one case the argument to Button is a function, in the other case it is the result of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, When python compiles `command=counter(var)`, it calls the function and assigns its result to `command`. You called `counter` and your callback is now `None` and that's obviously not what you want.

You can't just do `command=counter` which would simply make `counter` the function to use in the callback because the API doesn't have a way to include arguments for the callback. So you do

```
command=lambda:counter(var)
```

This assigns an anonymous function that takes no parameters to `command` just like the API wants. The lambda contains a reference to `var` in the containing scope which it then uses to call `counter`. And that's how you created a parameter for the target callback you really wanted.

This reference is a bit strange. Its a reference to the `var` slot in the containing scope, not the object that happens to be in `var` at the time of assignment. If you change `var` before the callback is made (or the containing scope disappears as in locals disappearing on return from a function), that new object is used. So, put your code in a function so you don't drive yourself crazy!

Comment: You can also use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)  to bind `var` in a closure. `tkinter.Button(window, textvariable=var, command=partial(counter, var))`